# how can i send data from one page to another?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm trying to send the data from a textfield  of a page to another textfield that is in another page without getting out from the first one
i tried using form and javascript,but wheni click the button it goes to the second page or it says that it doesnt exist (when i tried other ways),and i couldnt send the data to the second page,

```
<script>
                function carrinho()
                {
                  var codProduto = document.getElementById('proc´[]').value;
                  var quantidade = document.getElementById('txtNumber').value;
                  var dataString = 'codProduto='+codProduto +'&quantidade'+quantidade;
                  $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"C:\xampp\htdocs\prototype\views\orcamento.php",
                    dara: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                      $('#smg').html(html);
                    }
                  });
                    return false;
                }

                </script>
          <form action="http://localhost/prototype/orcamento.php" method="post">
                  <td><img src="css/imagens/catalogomiluz/S3B60340.png" width="200" height="200" /></td>
                  <td><input id="proc" name="proc[]" type='text' class="form-control" value="000712S3B60340" readonly></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="descProduto[]" id="descProduto" class="form-control" readonly></td>
                  <td><input id="prc" name="prc[]" type='text' class="form-control" value="" readonly></td>
                  <td style="width:60px;">
                       <input id="txtNumber" type="number" value="1"   />
                       <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="+" onclick="add();" />
                      <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="-"  onclick="subtract();" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <input id="carrinhoTemp" type="image" alt="submit" img src="css/imagens/carrinho.png" onclick=" return carrinho()" />
                  </td>
                </form>
```

the code from the second page look like this:

```
 <?php
 $codProduto=$_POST['$codProduto']
 $qtdProduto=$_POST['$quantidade']
  ?> 

 <td><input type="text" name="codProduto" id="codProduto" value="<?php  echo htmlentities($codProduto); ?>" maxlength="20"></td>
 <td><input type="number" name="qtdProduto" id="qtdProduto" value="<?php  echo htmlentities($qtdProduto); ?>" maxlength="5"></td>
```

Comment: just use the form and post\get, -> php, there is no need for ajax here.

Comment: your php contains errors.

Comment: @rtfm can youtell me how do i use it without changing pages?

Comment: not submit the form, not have that code on another page but on the same page, then you can populate it with JS (no php)- still no AJAX

Comment: Why you are using url like this url:"C:\xampp\htdocs\prototype\views\orcamento.php" . please use http://prototype\views\orcamento.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it something like bellow. I simplified the code for better understanding.

@rtfm recommends to provide the content only with javascript. You could do this. Or not. It depends on how your app is structured and/or which tasks are involved. You can use only js for a little response content, but, if the content is big, then it's better to load it through ajax from an external page. Also, as long as at least one simple server-side operation is required before providing a response content, then you'll have to use ajax. Or form submit.

I don't know how you use `proc[]`, e.g. in which context, so my code is just an example with a normal name (`proc`).

If you have `td` tags directly surrounded by `form` tags, then it's wrong. `form` tags should reside between `td` tags, or surrounding the `table` tags. Nowhere else when it's about displaying forms and tables together.

Any special reson, why you want to deactivate caching? If nothing special, then remove the `caching: false` line.

Good luck!

---

#### Option 1: One page, one form, no ajax request:

```
<?php
$response = FALSE;

/*
 * ===================================
 * Run operations upon form submission
 * ===================================
 */
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /*
     * ==========================
     * Validate the posted values
     * ==========================
     */
    if (!isset($_POST['proc']) || empty($_POST['proc'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide a proc.';
    }

    /*
     * =====================================
     * Assign the posted values to variables
     * =====================================
     */
    if (!isset($errors)) {
        $codProduto = htmlentities($_POST['proc']);

        $response = TRUE;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="messages">
            <?php
            if (isset($errors)) {
                echo implode('<br/>', $errors);
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="proc" name="proc" value="000712S3B60340" class="form-control">

            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                <img id="carrinhoTemp" src="css/imagens/carrinho.png" alt="submit" />
            </button>
        </form>

        <div id="smg">
            <?php
            if ($response) {
                ?>
                <input type="text" id="codProduto" name="codProduto" value="<?php echo isset($codProduto) ? $codProduto : ''; ?>" maxlength="20">
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

#### Option 2: Two pages, no form, an ajax request:

**1st page (index.php):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function carrinho() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'orcamento.php',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        'codProduto': $('#proc').val()
                    },
                    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        $('#messages').html('');
                        if (response.errors.length > 0) {
                            $('#messages').html(response.errors.join('<br/>'));
                        } else {
                            $('#smg').html(response.content);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('An error occurred during your request. Please try again, or contact us.');
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="messages"></div>

        <input type="text" id="proc" name="proc" value="000712S3B60340" class="form-control">
        <input type="image" id="carrinhoTemp" src="css/imagens/carrinho.png" onclick="carrinho();" alt="submit" />

        <div id="smg"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**2nd page (orcamento.php):**

```
<?php

/*
 * =========================
 * Array holding the results
 * =========================
 */
$response = [
    'content' => '',
    'errors' => [],
];

/*
 * ==========================
 * Validate the posted values
 * ==========================
 */
if (!isset($_POST['codProduto']) || empty($_POST['codProduto'])) {
    $response['errors'][] = 'Please provide a codProduto.';
}

/*
 * ================================================================================
 * Assign the required html content to the response, if the posted values are valid
 * ================================================================================
 */
if (!$response['errors']) {
    $codProduto = htmlentities($_POST['codProduto']);

    $response['content'] .= '<td><input type="text" id="codProduto" name="codProduto" value="' . $codProduto . '" maxlength="20"></td>';
}

/*
 * ==================================
 * Json-encode and print the response
 * ==================================
 */
echo json_encode($response);
```